# How to pin to start menu using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, startmenu

I can pin some programs to taskbar on Win7 using PowerShell.

```c
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Windows')    
$item = $folder.Parsename('notepad.exe')
$verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Tas&kbar'}
if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}
```

How do I modify the above code to pin a program to the Start menu?

Comment: Don't. This is the user's decision, not yours. Same with the taskbar, actually. There is no programmatic access to this *on purpose*.

Comment: Why? Is it prejudicial? Moreover I tried it for start menu. But it does not work.

Comment: [Why is there no programmatic access to the Start menu pin list?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx)

Comment: I have to do it. Because, I want to create a standard developer machine. All machines must be same. Taskbars, start menus... When developers changed their machines, they mustn't have any concord problem in the future

Comment: There are ways to do so in Windows images you roll out. IIRC via the System Image Manager and answer files for unattended installation.

Comment: You can find more info for create/customize/deploy a windows7 image here http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee523217(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Joey, your comments apply to windows XP. This question is clearly tagged Windows 7. Your link really confused me until I saw it was written in 2003.

Comment: @NH.: It still applies, though. Pretty much all user interface things that the user should be able to customize have no public, supported API to change them programmatically. That is intentional.

Answer (score 7):

Another way

```c
$sa = new-object -c shell.application
$pn = $sa.namespace($env:windir).parsename('notepad.exe')
$pn.invokeverb('startpin')
```

Or unpin

```c
$pn.invokeverb('startunpin')
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer I've seen.

Comment: How do you set the name you'd like displayed?

Answer (score 4):

Use the code below

```c
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Windows')    
$item = $folder.Parsename('notepad.exe')
$verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Start Men&u'}
if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}
```

Note: the change is in the fourth line.

Comment: This will work for the current user, how can I get it pinned for all users?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with most of the solution is that they enumerate the verbs on a file, search for the string to perform the action (“Pin to Startmenu” etc.) and then execute it. This does not work if you need to support 30+ languages in your company, except you use external function to search for the localized command (see answer from [shtako-verflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357275/shtako-verflow)).

The answer from [Steven Penny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny) is the first that is language neutral and does not need any external code. It uses the verbs stored in the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{90AA3A4E-1CBA-4233-B8BB-535773D48449}` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}`

Based on this, here’s the code we are now using:

```
function PinToTaskbar {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
  ExecuteVerb $FilePath "taskbarpin" 
}

function UnpinFromTaskbar {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
  ExecuteVerb $FilePath "taskbarunpin" 
}

function PinToStartmenu {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
 ExecuteVerb $FilePath "startpin" 
}

function UnpinFromStartmenu {
         param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath)  
 ExecuteVerb $FilePath "startunpin" 
}

function ExecuteVerb {  
         param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$File,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Verb
         ) 

    $path = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($File) 
    $basePath = split-path $path -parent   #retrieve only the path File=C:\Windows\notepad.exe -> C:\Windows
    $targetFile = split-path $path -leaf    #retrieve only the file File=C:\Windows\notepad.exe -> notepad.exe

    $shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
    $folder = $shell.Namespace($basePath)        
    if ($folder)
    {
       $item = $folder.Parsename($targetFile) 

       if ($item)
       {
         $item.invokeverb($Verb)
         # "This method does not return a value." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
         # Therefore we have no chance to know if this was successful...
         write-host "Method [$Verb] executed for [$path]"       
       } 
       else
       {
         write-host "Target file [$targetFile] not found, aborting" 
       }             
    }
    else 
    {      
      write-host "Folder [$basePath] not found, aborting" 
    }

}


#PinToTaskbar "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"
#UnpinFromTaskbar "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"

PinToStartmenu "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"
#UnpinFromStartmenu "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

See the script (international) here : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750

If you want to add an action like Pin to Modern UI interface (Windows 8), at $verbs, add 51201

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Penny's second answer above worked well for me.  Here are a couple more tidbits.

It's doing COM through PowerShell, so you can do the same thing with pretty much any COM client.  For example, here's an AutoHotkey version.

```
Shell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
Target := Shell.Namespace(EnvGet("WinDir")).ParseName("Notepad.exe")
Target.InvokeVerb("startpin")
```

VBScript or InnoSetup would look almost the same except for the function used to create the object.

I also found that I have one program that pinned OK, but didn't have the right icon and/or description because of limitations in the compiler.  I just made a little 1-line WinForms app that starts the target with Process.Start, and then added the appropriate icon, and the name I wanted in the Start Menu in the Title property in AppInfo.cs.